# How to add array of array of Strings in mongodb schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**This is my sample docs**

```
const a = [{
maintag: "This is main Tag 1",
subtag: ["This is subtag a", "This is subtag b"]}, {
maintag: "This is main Tag 2",
subtag: ["This is subtag c", "This is subtag d"]
}]
```

I want to store it in MongoDB database. What will the schema for storing this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
let schema = new Schema({
   yourData: {
      maintag: {type: String},
      subtag: [String]
   }
});
```

Comment: I have two arrays. "yourData" will be in between an array of objects. Please see the structure.